# AllocConsole() variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I need to startup a console that stays inside a window in win-form.
My question is,

How do i keep a console inside a win-form panel. when you drag the form around it sticks inside that certain panel.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: No, it's not. You may want to ask a question about your actual problem instead of your proposed solution, that will result in more helpful answers.

Comment: I Want a console to stick inside a panel of win-form. I got the code for a program to run inside the panel. But have no idea for a console. thank you for your response

Comment: You cannot do this. What you can do is start a process with your program and capture the output of the external program and write it into a read-only textbox that you set to white font on block background.

Comment: It's not possible to startup a console through code and keep it inside a certain win-form panel? Because it is possible with programs.

Comment: Erm, console is still just an application... If you know how to embed a different application, did you try it with console as well? Should work exactly the same...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I use some certain methods that can only use when a process.start is called. But the idea is not totally broken. i am editing the question

Answer (score 1):

The only chance you have of making something work with `AllocConsole` is to:

1. Call `AllocConsole`.
2. Enumerate the top level windows in the system to find the window which houses the console.
3. Call `SetParent` to make the console window a child of a window in your application.
4. Position and size the window appropriately for its new parent.
5. Remove the non-client chrome of the console window by modifying the window styles.

However, I have very little faith that this solution will yield something usable. Almost certainly you'll need to implement your own console window.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried this, couldn't get it working.

Comment: Well, keep trying. This does work. Whether or not it looks good or is usable is another matter.